# I need to get the 5 posts with the most likes

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm currently making a news system, and I need to get the top 5 posts with the most likes. Below my code and tables:

**Models:**

Post:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use HasTags;

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function likes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(PostLike::class);
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(PostComment::class);
    }
}
```

Likes:

```
class PostLike extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'post_id', 'is_liked'];
    
    public function user(){
       return $this->belongsTo(User::class); 
    }
    public function post(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
    }
    use HasFactory;
}
```

**Tables:**

posts:
[posts table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pl48w.png)

post_likes:
[post likes table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLrwO.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No idea why you have a `is_liked` bool since if the relation exists, its liked. but this should work

`Post::withCount('likes')->orderBy('likes_count', 'desc')->take(5)->get();`

Comment: It's because the "like" can be positive or negative (like it, I don't like it)

Comment: well the code above will only return based on most relations, positive and negative.